# Show status window from Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a Windows service written in .NET with C#.  I know from here: [Launching GUI App from Windows Service - Window Does Not Appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109271/launching-gui-app-from-windows-service-window-does-not-appear).  that I can allow the service to interact with the desktop.  From Windows 7, however, I just get a dialog telling me "A program running on this computer is trying to display a message".  The service is an update service (think Windows update) I wanted to pop up a dialog telling the user that an update is taking place and informing them of the progress.

1) Can I display a window from a service in Windows 7?

2) Can I detect from within the service whether it can interact with the desktop?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: This approach is not recommended by microsoft for security reasons. The recommended approach is having a monitoring application running in a user session that communicates with your service and takes care of GUI interaction.

Comment: What do you wish to communicate? Windows Service sends messages to be displayed by a GUI app. Or other way around? GUI App controls/configures Windows Service?

Comment: The service is applying updates, so, I think I need to have the service send a message to a UI to give the user a status.  But, I get the idea.  Let the service be in the background, and run the status monitor in a user session.

Comment: As an FYI, you can detect whether you can interact with the desktop by checking the System.Environment.UserInteractive property. However, in Vista+, even if UserInteractive is true, you cannot directly access the GUI from a service, so it's useless for anything later than XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't display UI from a service.

The normal approach to this problem is to run a standard app in the user's desktop and have the service communicate with that app using your preferred form of IPC.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [.NET Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: .NET remoting was great in .NET 1.1 (ok, really not even then). Go with WCF if  you need to communicate between processes in Windows.

Comment: I find IPC is far easier to implement in .NET remoting than WCF. For something as trivial as just displaying a message from a service I personally don't think WCF is worth the extra effort.