# How to run external application from a Java EE web application?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, service, external

I have been working on a Web Application for Intranet use only. I work with Apache 7 and Windows Server 2003.

In one of my page, I need to open an external application that we can locate in C:/Program Files/etc... with some parameters already initialized. Of course, the user has to use the web application on the server to make it work (that will be the case).

To open the application, I use the `ProcessBuilder` object.

**The problem:**

When I work locally with Eclipse and run the server by hand, it works perfectly. Any application can open itself from a web page.
But when I use the tomcat windows service (and that's what we want to use on the server), it just never launches. Or to be more specific, it launches and stops the application directly. No java errors thrown and `process.waitFor()` with an exit value of 0. The fact is that we can run processes via the web application (I tried to run simple batch files), but when there is an UI involved, it will never appear.

Again, on the server this time, if I launch tomcat7.exe (that we can find in the %CATALINA_HOME%/bin directory) with a double click or cmd, the UI in the web application will appear. If I launch it with services.msc or tomcat7w.exe or `tomcat7 start` via cmd, it will not.

I thought of several things:

- use another user to start the service
- change the way the service is launched (StartMode: jvm, java. I did not succeed with exe)
  I read [Tomcat 7 Windows Service How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html) many times but didn't find out anything to solve my issue.

Have you any idea of what is happening, and how to solve this issue ?
What is the big difference between running tomcat as a service and from the command line?

Comment: First glance is the environments are probably different (things like what's on the path and other env variables are not set / set differently). Can you add a snippet of your actual ProcessBuilder related code (i.e. the command you are calling, and all the arguments being passed)

Comment: It wasn't an environment issue. The thing is that it's not recommanded to launch UI application through a windows service. In fact, my application was launched, but I couldn't see it. It only appears on session 0, that we can access via remote desktop connection with the /admin option.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1
If you open your service's properties window, go to the Log On tab then check the "Allow service to interact with desktop" check box you will get the behavior you want. Also depending on what app you what to run you may need to change the log on account.

### see [Launching GUI App from Windows Service - Window Does Not Appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109271/launching-gui-app-from-windows-service-window-does-not-appear)

Option 2
Did you try start a cmd and there use 
start /c "c:\path to\exe"

in cmd.exe type 
help start

---

Option 3

You will need a daemon service that is not run as a service. windows puts certain restrictions on service apps.

This sleeping app can be started by tomcat or other your self. it can listen on a port or poll a folder for a new file, and when it gets a job to do it starts the app you want. Via port or text file you can send the parameters.