# Running process from hidden window

Tags: c#, windows, process

I have faced a strange problem when trying to run a process from hidden window - the process I run runs in hidden like my process, Am I doing something wrong? I want to run that child process not hidden.

```
Process.Start(Path.GetTempPath() + "cleanup.exe", Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath);
```

Comment: What is it the strange problem that have ocurred?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with creating an object of `Process` class as below :

```
Process objProcess = new Process();            
objProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
objProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
objProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
objProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

// Passing the batch file/exe name
objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = string.Format(strBatchFileName);

// Passing the argument
objProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(strArgument);
try
{
 objProcess.Start();
}
catch
{
 throw new Exception("Batch file is not found for processing");
}
```

Comment: I want to run that child process not hidden.

Comment: then you can change `WindowStyle` Property

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Also, I'm trying to run this process from service.

Comment: Are you executing this process from service and want to show in the front ?

Comment: its not possible in this way, service has no output window

Comment: So how is this possible in other way?

Comment: Would you be kind and write the answer?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180833/why-cant-windows-services-have-a-gui

Comment: As you can see I'm trying to run a process from a service process, not creating a GUI in service process.

Comment: first try it your self, if you get stuck then come to stackoverflow

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109271/launching-gui-app-from-windows-service-window-does-not-appear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063731/is-there-any-way-to-start-a-gui-application-from-a-windows-service-on-windows-7

Comment: Hey, running a process (as in some other executable that you wrote) from a Windows Service is usually not allowed. There is something called the shatter hole (google this) which windows tries to prevent opening due to services and programs having different permissions. Perhaps you don't need a service and just need a program that runs when the user logs on or something of like that.

Comment: see, untill you dont try by yourself no body will help you. so first help your self and then expect help from others